# Refactor a switch case with java lambdas

Tags: java, lambda

I am trying to re-factor a legacy code and in this case I have a huge block of switch case which decide which command to be executed

```
switch(operation)
case addition  : return add(int a, String b, String c);
case multiply  : return multiply(int a, int b);
case substract : return substract(int a, int b);
```

Approach 1 : using polymorphism

```
public interface Operation {
    void performOperation(int a, int b);
}
```

Then fill a map with the available implementations:

```
Map<Key, Operation> actions = new HashMap<>();
actions.add(addition, new addOperation());
actions.add(multiply, new multiplyOperation());
actions.add(substract, new substractOperation());
```

Then I can refer the map when I need to perform a operation.

The issues I have with this approach is that I am having to create a large number of classes / annonymous classes

Approach 2 : Using Enum

```
public enum MyKeyEnum {
    ADDITION {
        public void performOperation(int a, int b) {
            // Perform addition
        }
    },
    MULTIPLY {
        public void performOperation(int a, int b) {
            // Perform Multiplication
        }
    };

    public abstract void performOperation(int counter, String dataMain, String dataSub);
    }
```

This approach is actually better of the two but I saw another eaxmple in Java 8 and want use something like this

As all these are following a pattern I tried to use Functional Interface and Maps

```
final static Map<String, Supplier<IAction>> map = new HashMap<>();
static {
    map.put("add", Addition::new);
    map.put("multiply", Multiply::new);
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Supplier<IAction> action = map.get("add");
    System.out.println(action.get().performAction(10,10));

    action = map.get("multiply");
    System.out.println(action.get().performAction(10,10));
}
```

But this again has the disadvantages of the first approach so wanted to see if I can use lambdas like I used Enum implementation
There is a partial function implementation provided in Java 8 which I wanted to utilize
Example :

```
BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> minus = (x, y) -> x - y;
Function<Integer, Integer> subtractor = partial(minus, 10);
System.out.println(subtractor.apply(4)); // 6
```

as BiFunction is accepting only 2 parameters I created a Trifuction like

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface TriFunction<T, U, V, R> {
    R apply(T a, U b, V c);
}

public static <T, U, V, R> Function<V, R> partial(TriFunction<T, U, V, R> f, T x, U y) {
    return (z) -> f.apply(x, y, z);
}
```

This will resolve the issue to an extent but I am not able to figure out how I can add this to the map and dynamically pass values

```
Map<String, TriFunction<String, Integer, Integer, Operation>> map
= new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How does your interface `TriFunction` replace the switch?

Comment: The simpler approach would be polymorphism: make operation an enum, and use `operation.perform(a, b, c)`.

Comment: @Flown I wanted to see if there was another approach using lambda, as my approach was complicating the map signature

Comment: @JBNizet I did start with using polymorphism, but the switch case in question had about 50 possibilities, and I did not want to create that many classes.
So with this approach I wanted to use lambda to get this to work like a runtime anonymous inner class.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I will add key as the operation name and the value would be a a method reference that had the implementation.

Comment: Can you show us some test data or the real use case? This question is a bit too broad. How are your `perofmOPX` look like?

Comment: Please show more code. Where do you get your operation value from?

Comment: @Flown I have updated the question with more code

Comment: @VladimirKorenev updated the question to give better clarity

Comment: [Polymorphism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc). See from 7:40.

Comment: @Sudheer, i understand better why you chose the 2d approach. The fact is, with Java, you can create only 1 class per file. I hope, this feature goes away some day, as well as much of the boiler plate it needs. I have recently tryied Kotlin language which is worth a try. Cheers :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are already there. If you've a method which has the same signature of your interface you can also pass it to your operation repository like:

```
Map<String, IntBinaryOperator> operations = new HashMap<>();
operations.put("add", Integer::sum);
operations.put("subtract", (a, b) -> a - b);
operations.put("multiply", (a, b) -> a * b);
//...
System.out.println(operations.get("multiply").applyAsInt(10, 20));
```

Answer (score 1):

Thx for your question, as i stumbled on the exact same problem. I was looking for a way to eliminate `if if if` or `switch` blocks in my code for some time.

I opted for the `Map` + `Supplier` approach, implemented within a factory, as in the following snippet:

```
public class OperatorFactory {
    private final String supportedOperatorsRegex = "\\+|\\*|-";
    private Map<String, Supplier<Operator>> supportedOperators = ImmutableMap.of(
        "+", Addition::new, "*", Multiplication::new, "-", Subtraction::new, "ID", Identity::new
    );

    public Operator parseToOperator(String input) {
        return supportedOperators.get(extractOperator(input)).get();
    }

    private String extractOperator(String input) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(supportedOperatorsRegex).matcher(input);

        if (matcher.find()) return matcher.group();
        if (input.matches("\\d+")) return "ID";

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unsupported operation: " + input);
    }
}
```

I find this sollution closer to the Open / Close Principle (the O in SOLID principles):

1. Now, all i need to do to extend the functionalities is to add another operator class that implements some `Operator` interface that i have defined elsewhere, add it in the `supportedOperators` map and in the `SupportedOperatorsRegex` without changing any of the business logic of the `OperatorFactory` class.
2. Moreover, the client classes do not need to know what is happening in the `OperatorFactory`, and that is less coupling.